# In mongoose, is there a difference between .sort().skip() and .skip().sort()?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As you can see the title, there is difference of `.sort().skip()` and `.skip().sort()`?

Does `mongoose` handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no difference. `.sort()` gets always applied **before** `.skip()` which makes sense since you want to get results in deterministic order to be able to skip some of them in a predictable manner.

Below queries will return different results since `.skip()` and `.sort()` will get reordered for query and kept in specified order for `.aggregate()`:

```
let results = await Test.aggregate([{ $skip: 2 }, { $sort: { a: 1 } }]);

let results2 = await Test.find().skip(2).sort({ a: 1 });
```

Internally second syntax simply builds an object of [.find() options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) where there order of keys doesn't matter:

```
Mongoose: tests.find({}, { skip: 2, sort: { a: 1 }, projection: {} })
```

or

```
Mongoose: tests.find({}, { sort: { a: 1 }, skip: 2, projection: {} })
```

You can add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to track that.